# Splice one item from 2 or more items randomly in Javascript array

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have this simple array here

```
let list = [5,6,7,89,0,8754,44];
```

In this array, I don't want `5` and `8754` to be together so I need to remove one randomly each time.

These 2 numbers can be anywhere so I don't know their position. So to fix this I have written this code

```
firstNumber =  list.findIndex((element) => element == 5);
secondNumber = list.findIndex((element) => element == 8754)
```

But before removing one I need to check if they are both present on the array

```
if(firstNumber > -1 && secondNumber > -1){
```

And after that I write the logic of to generate a number from 0 1 and splice the random item

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1) + 0);
  
  let randomInc = [firstNumber,secondNumber][randomNumber]
  
  list.splice(randomInc,1);
```

Full code

```
let list = [5,6,7,89,0,8754,44];

//get random


firstNumber =  list.findIndex((element) => element == 5);
secondNumber = list.findIndex((element) => element == 8754)

//both are presents
if(firstNumber > -1 && secondNumber > -1){
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1) + 0);
  
  let randomInc = [firstNumber,secondNumber][randomNumber]
  
  list.splice(randomInc,1);
}


console.log(list)
```

The code works fine for 2 numbers but how can I improve it to make it for multiple numbers like 3 or more?
Can anyone add any suggestion here

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this should do it:

```js
function process(list, numbers) {
  let indices = numbers.map(it => list.findIndex(num => num === it));

  if (indices.every(it => it !== -1)) {
    firstNumber = list.findIndex((element) => element == 5);
    secondNumber = list.findIndex((element) => element == 8754)

    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (indices.length - 0) + 0);
    let randomInc = indices[randomNumber]

    list.splice(randomInc, 1);
  }

  console.log(list);
}

let inputList = [5, 6, 7, 89, 0, 8754, 44];

process([...inputList], [5, 8754]); // removes any of the 2 numbers
process([...inputList], [7, 89, 44]); // removes any of the 3 numbers
process([...inputList], [4, 5, 6]); // will return complete list
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, maybe this is what you want:

```
function removeRandom(list, ...items) {
    const indexes = items.map(item => list.findIndex(listItem => listItem === item));

    if(indexes.every(index => index !== -1)) {
        const randomIndex = indexes[Math.floor(Math.random()*indexes.length)];
        list.splice(randomIndex, 1);
        return list;
    } else {
        return -1
    }
};

console.log(removeRandom([5,6,7,89,0,8754,44], 5, 8754, 44, 89));
// [6, 7, 89, 0, 8754, 44]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let list = [5,6,7,89,0,8754,44];

let arr=[5,89,8754]
let numberArr=[]

arr.forEach((item,index)=>{
 numberArr.push(list.findIndex((element) => element == item))
})

let max = numberArr.length
let min = 0
let randomNmuber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)

let randomInc =  numberArr[randomNmuber]
  list.splice(randomInc,1);

console.log(list)
```

you can try this

Answer (score 1):

```js
let list = [5,6,7,89,0,8754,44];
const conflictingNumbers = [5, 8754, 44];

const conflicingIndexes = list.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => conflictingNumbers.indexOf(cur) > -1 ? [...acc, idx] : acc, []);

const randomConflictingIndex = conflicingIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random()*conflicingIndexes.length)];

const result = list.filter((_, idx) => randomConflictingIndex !== idx);

console.log(result)
```